# Ripping unnecessary/unused modules from Liferay portal

Tags: customization, liferay, portal, enterprise-portal

We are using only portal part of the liferay to show data from some of our applications. It is done thro liferay-ext. Is it possible to rip out the modules unused by us like communities, forums, blogs etc that we dont use. These seem to be hogging tomcat memory.

Thanks
Rama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deactivate some portlets that you don't use from ext, it should be available in liferay's administration guide or developer guide on https://www.liferay.com/documentation. Depending on the amount of work you're prepared to put into this you might also want to think about dimensions of your caches and other settings. However, I consider an additional piece of memory to be a lot cheaper than investing the time (again on each update) to trim down Liferay, if it's only for memory reasons.

However, if you "easily" trim Liferay through some means, please provide your findings in the Liferay forums as well - it might be worth feeding it back.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for your inputs. Since we are sharing this memory with other apps on 32bit server - we are forced to reduce its footprint. As of now, we ran a dependancy analyzer on the src version of liferay and trying to remove the ones with least dependancies. We do are working out the ways to handle upgrades